# How to review code that was submitted to me in RTC with "submit for review" feature?

Tags: rtc, ibm-jazz

I'm using RTC,
my friends submitted their change sets for review, and I'm the reviewer. I can't find their change sets anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This thread](https://jazz.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21584&view=next&sid=033b5f2bf7bee9d8cc9a1d632df414c9) summarizes the process:

### Project configuration:

> - Precondition set: "`Require Work Item Approval`" for "`Deliver (client)`" operation for "`Everyone`" role.
> - In the "`Required approvals`", for the "`Review`" type, at least one from "`Everyone`" role (or "`Team Member`" role) is set.
>
> "`User may overrule`" may also be checked if not all code delivery may require a review process.

### Scenario:

There are three developers - `D1`, `D2` & `D3` - all using RTC Eclipse client.

> - `D1` does the code change for files `f1` & `f2` in her local workspace and saves them. f1 and f2 appears as unresolved in the pending changes view.
> - `D1` checks-in f1 & f2 into a new change set "`CS`".
>     Right clicks on "`CS`" and select "`Submit for Review`" menu option and associate to a WI (existing or a new one) and select approvers:
>
>   - `D2` as the approver for `f1` review (subject field is used to tell what to review) and
>   - `D3` as approver for `f2` review.
> - The approval/Review process will be in the pending state.
> - `D2` & `D3` gets intimation of the review task assigned to them through a query - "Pending approvals for me".
> - `D2` opens the WI and in the Links section, double clicks on the `f1` in the change set and see the diff in the Change Explorer.
>     Does the review.
>     Optionally, adds comment for `D1` in the discussion field of the `WI`.
>     Changes the `Review` approval state from `pending` to `approved`.
>     `D3` follows the same process as `D2` but rejects because the `f3` code change is not acceptable. Changes the `Review` approval state from `pending` to `rejected`.
> - `D1` gets the review comment via email/feed - because `D1` is the owner and the subscriber of the WI.
> - `D1` fixes the code in `f2` based on `D3`'s review and checks in to the same changeset.
> - `D1` adds `D3` again for the new review approval in the same WI.
> - `D3` gets intimation of the review task assigned to him through a query - "`Pending approvals for me`".
> - `D3` opens the WI and in the Links section, double clicks on the `f2` in the change set and see the diff in the Change Explorer.
>     Does the review.
>     Optionally, adds comment for `D1` in the discussion field of the WI.
>     Changes the Review approval state from `pending` to `approved`.
> - `D1` gets the review comment via email/feed - because `D1` is the owner and the subscriber of the WI.
> - `D1` delivers the changeset (or invokes "`Complete`" action on the changeset) because all the approvals in the WI are in approved state.
> - The complete history of the code review process (rejected ones, approved ones) are in the "`Approvals`" tab.

Answer (score 7):

You can also create a work item query that finds all approvals that are open against you. Mine looks like:

[image]

I have that configured as a section in the My Work view, so I know when I have stuff to review.

Comment: +1 on the query. You can even share it with the protect/team area, since the approver is "current user".